# How to change the output language of the day of the week from English to Ukrainian using the datetime library in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a telegram bot in Ukrainian, and in order to display information related to a specific day of the week, I need to compare the current day of the week with the text read by the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to set locale for the Ukrainian, then text should change accordingly.

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "uk_UA.utf8")

now = datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))
```

Comment: LC_TIME produces an arbitrary set of characters, but LC_ALL works. Thank you!